# How to create a user account with a name longer than 20 characters in Windows Server 2019 which is not part of a domain?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-server-2019

Probably identified as a duplicate soon, but I couldn't find a solution despite of substantial effort ... Having said this:

By accident, several hours ago I noticed that I obviously can't create a new user account with a name longer than 20 characters on our Windows 2019 server, using the computer management console. In the `New User` dialog box, the text field `User name:` just doesn't let me type in more than 20 characters.

I then tried using the command line and the `net user` command, but that does not work either. This problem is known to Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/net-add-not-support-names-exceeding-20-characters

That document recommends working with the GUI computer management:

> The same action does work with the GUI Computer Management, Local Users, and Groups Microsoft Management Console (MMC).

This is clearly wrong: The `compmgmt.mmc` console, as stated above, does not let me type in user names longer than 20 characters.

The document also mentions `cusrmgr.exe`, which I don't have. The server in question is not part of a domain, and that tool seems to be part of the Windows 2000 Resource Kit (seriously?) which I don't have access to. The document also mentions that the goal can be achieved via VB scripts, but the example script it gives is completely useless for creating new accounts.

Now I am stuck. Could anybody please explain how I can create user accounts with names longer than 20 characters in Windows Server 2019?

Comment: TBH, I am a little bit upset about that question being closed. In what way is it seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations? In what way is it off-topic? I have asked a clear question about how to solve a concrete problem in Windows. Please explain; I am eager to learn.